# Creating Variable Sized char Array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to take in a char array that is oversized in order to place delimiters in it based on the variable `maxSize`

For example if the string `"This is a message"` is passed to the function along with a `maxSize` of `4` then the output should be `"This, is ,a me,ssag,e"`

```
char *placeDelimiter(char message[], int maxSize) {
  int msgSize = strlen(message);
  int delSize = (msgSize/maxSize);
  int remSize = msgSize%maxSize;
  int newSize = msgSize+delSize;
  if (remSize==0) delSize--; //removes delimiter if on end of char array
  char temp[newSize];
  int delPos = 0;
  for (int x=0;x<msgSize;x++) {
    if ((x+1)%maxSize == 0) temp[x] = ',';
    temp[x+delPos] = message[x];
    delPos = (x+1)/maxSize;
  } 
  return (char *)temp;
}

int main()
{
    char msg[] = "This is a message";
    char *p;
    p = placeDelimiter(msg, 4);
    printf("%s", p);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I am getting the output `"This i,"` from the input `"This is a message"` (From an online compiler). Can anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char temp[newSize];` is a local variable to the function `placeDelimiter()`. Accessing it after the function has returned is Undefined behavior.

You should use dynamic memory allocation.

```
char* temp = malloc(newSize);
```